# How to permanently change umask value from 0002 to 0022?

Tags: umask

My current umask value is `0002`

```
$ umask
0002
$
```

I want to permanently change it to `0022`

How can I do so?

Answer (score 3):

Go to terminal

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

In terminal type

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Search for `umask`

If present change the current value to `umask 022`

Save and exit

If not present, add the following line to end of document

```
umask 022
```

Save and exit

Now logout and login

Reopen terminal and type

```
umask
```

You will get

```
0022
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been searching for half hour and finally out this solution for my own `umask` setting. Was having trouble editing photos that kept defaulting to `600` but I wanted `644`.